# how libvirt cputune config goes to qemu-kvm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, vcpu, numa

I am porting xml libvirt config to qemu executable arguments. Simply I have .xml vm config from `virsh edit vm-name` and I want to run the same vm machine by executing `qemu-system-x86_64` with special command line parameters. Die to my specific needs I cannot use `libvirt`. The problem is that .xml vm config uses special cpu mapping from host machine:

```
<cputune>
    <vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='3'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0-2'/>
    <emulatorpin cpuset='0-2'/>
</cputune>
```

and then uses these vcpus in cpu numa config:

```
<cpu>
    <numa>
        <cell cpus='0' memory='2097152'/>
        <cell cpus='1' memory='2097152'/>
    </numa>
</cpu>
```

I map numa config this way: `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -numa node,nodeid=0,cpus=0,mem=2048 -numa node,nodeid=1,cpus=1,mem=2048` but I do not know how to specify vcpu config for `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64`. That is the problem. Any ideas?

PS My specific task is to run specific vm with vcpu tuning under Kata-containers runtime because I want to run such vm under Docker or Kubernetes. So I need to patch kata-runtime. Kata-runtime runs qemu-kvm vms using [Intel GoVmm](https://github.com/intel/govmm) which can only run qemu binary with command line parameters. At the moment I am patching govmm for my specific needs. Intel govmm does not use libvirt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are set up using cgroups and not qemu options. You can achieve it using `cpuset` cgroup subsystem. You can get cgroup settings from running qemu process by running `cat /proc/<qemu pid>/cgroups`.

See also: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html